# Excel 2016: Adding Gradient Formats for Cell Background and Font?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2016 to construct a forecast model with a range of outputs. I have used Excel's built-in Conditional Formatting setting (Graded Color Scale, to be precise) to make the outputs visually informative, setting a green gradient scale to distinguish between low-valued outputs and high-valued outputs.

The minimum-valued cell background is set to '*Green, Accent 6, Lighter 80%*' and the maximum-valued cell background is set to '*Green, Accent 6*'. This has worked well. The cell values near the maximum, however, can sometimes be difficult to read, since they are 'Black, Text 1' (not a great contrast with the darker *Green*).

I am hoping to add the same type of conditional formatting to the cell texts in the range of outputs to generate a color contrast: for example, in the lighter end of the gradient, the cell texts will be '*Black, Text*', and in the darker end of the gradient, the cells texts will be '*White, Background*.' Visually, that would solve my contrast issue.

Unfortunately, after reading through this forum and searching for conditional formatting guides on Google, I haven't found a solution on how to apply the two types of formatting (background and font) to the same range of cells. I am not practiced in VBA, so I am hoping for any pointer that involves Excel's native functionality, if that's possible.

To boil all this down into a one-liner: "How do I add gradient conditional formatting to both font and background to a range of cells?"

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past by creating a number of rules that give the appearance of a gradient on both. To do this however you would create as many rules you need to get the resolution you want. For example:

Suppose you want to assign font and background fill for each value in increments of 10% from 0 to 100%.

For this you need to get 10 font colors in rgb format that gradually shift in the gradient that you want here is a site that can help:

http://www.colorizer.org/

Then do the same with for you background colors.

Now pair a font and background color with the range that you want that rule to apply to and write the excel rule.

While this method is a pain to set up it avoids vba at all costs and if you use the sheet as a template for other sheets you won't have to mess with it much.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own sets of custom rules as per @rahicks answer in the most comprehensive way of doing this. If you have a fairly stable range of values, then a quick and dirty solution is to use Custom Number Formats.

On top of your current conditional formatting, apply a Custom Number Format using a condition. This example sets the colour to white if the value is greater than 50, and then uses the existing colour otherwise.

```
[White][>50]General;General
```

You'll need to replace `50` with the mid-point of your data range and you'll also need to replace both instances of `General` with whatever number format you currently have on the range.

[image: Format]